# Lisp why are my objects of the same instance?

Tags: arrays, lisp, common-lisp

So I wanted to remake a program that uses lists for containing objects and replace the lists with arrays.

And I ran into a problem in which my object is of the same instance

`(setq arr (make-array 3 :initial-element (make-instance 'object) :adjustable t :fill-pointer 3))`

after this code's execution

all of the objects in the array are the same
and the interpreter gives me this

`#(#<OBJECT {1002DFDD23}> #<OBJECT {1002DFDD23}> #<OBJECT {1002DFDD23}>)`

I know other ways to do this but still I want to know why does this happen?

and if it's no trouble what does `#<OBJECT {1002DFDD23}` mean as a whole and is this some sort memory address?

Comment: To pretty print objects: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/clos.html#38-pretty-printing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The form `(make-instance 'object)` is evaluated exactly once on invocation of your code.  The result is used as initial value for each element of the array.  It may help to see the singular word `initial-element` (not `-elements`), and that operators starting with `make-` are usually functions and thus all arguments are evaluated before invocation.

The output `#<OBJECT {1002DFDD23}>` is for an *unreadable object*.  This is indicated by the `#<` syntax, which is defined to signal an error when trying to `read` it (http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dht.htm).  It is usually produced by [`print-unreadable-object`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_pr_unr.htm#print-unreadable-object), which is usually used when defining methods for `print-object`.  The exact output is thus implementation or user defined (whoever wrote a `print-object` method for that particular class).  It will by default most likely contain the class name and something like a memory reference or address.

For completeness, I like to use `map-into`:

```
(map-into (make-array 3 :adjustable t :fill-pointer 3)
          (lambda () (make-instance 'object)))
```

to get an array initialized with distinct objects.

Answer (score 4):

`make-array` is a function. It’s arguments are evaluated before calling.

The following are equivalent:

```
(make-array 3
            :initial-element (make-instance 'object)
            :adjustable t
            :fill-pointer 3))
```

And

```
(let ((a 3)
      (b :initial-element)
      (c (make-instance 'object))
      (d :adjustable)
      (e t)
      (f :fill-pointer)
      (g 3))
  (make-array a b c d e f g))
```

Comment: a minor difference is that for the first form some Lisp compilers will check the argument keywords and warn if it is unknown, ...

Comment: That’s true although I’m not sure I’d count it as a semantic difference. One thing I don’t know is when the function name is evaluated. Ie is `#'make-array` computed before or after the arguments. Basically if evaluating one argument were to change the `symbol-function` of `make-array` then would the old or new function be called.

Comment: Since MAKE-ARRAY is a CL function, it is undefined what happens if you try to modify it. Even then, in some circumstances the function might be inlined and you would not see any effect modifying it - without recompilation of the using code.

Comment: Imagine that we are in a package where `make-array` is not `CL:make-array` and the function is declared not inline. Then what is the semantics of the order of evaluation of function and arguments.

Comment: Maybe it's not a semantic difference, but CL was specified to support the first case with compile time checks: missing keyword, wrong keyword, allowing additional keywords, etc.

Comment: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababc.htm says that the arguments are evaluated, then the functional value of the operator is retrieved from the lexical environment, then the function is invoked.

Comment: Modulo compiler optimizations, the equivalence in the answer seems to be correct.

Comment: As I said: whether the function gets actually retrieved from a binding / global symbol function cell is in the general case an implementation detail.. for example the file compiler is allowed to assume that a call to a function in the same file is always that function. Or if the function is declared to be inlined, a compiler may inline it. Or if the compiler chooses on its own to inline some functions...

Comment: Generally it's useful to remind users that your second form will actually work - which might be a surprise for some users who haven't seen functions with keyword arguments being called this way.

Answer (score 2):

[Common Lisp HyperSpec: Function MAKE-ARRAY](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_ar.htm#make-array):

> If initial-element is supplied, it is used to initialize each element of new-array